# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int^{2}_0 x^4 \cos(x/n)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int^{2\pi}_0 x^4 \cos(x/n)$$

[image]

This is my solution for the problem. I cannot upload the rest of the solution, but all I did after that was making more calculation and got to the fact that the limit is 0, but my teacher told me it is not.Could you help me?

Comment: Maybe the dominated convergence theorem works here, with $f_n(x)=x^4\cdot\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: HINT:  Note that $$\cos(x/n)=1-2\sin^2(x/2n)$$and that $$|\sin^2(x/2n)|\le x^2/4n^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also did the calculus and I think that you forgot to multiplicate the final result of the integral with $n^5$ and th result would be 32/5. Also, I did the same mistake when I solved your problem.
Also, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim+integral_0%5E2+x%5E4+%5Ccos+%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bn%7D+dx+n-%3Einf

Comment: Yes. I reviwed my calculus and saw that I did not multiplicated with n^5. Thank you!

Comment: Also the question in title compared to question 4 in the photo don't seem to agree - upper limit is 2 in photo, but $2\pi$ in S.E. question?

Answer (score 0):

if you can justify interchanging the limit and integral it is just:
$$\int_0^2x^4dx=\frac{32}5$$

Alternatively:
$$n^5\int_0^{2/n}x^4\cos(x)dx=n\left(24\sin\left(\dfrac{2}{n}\right)n^4-48\cos\left(\dfrac{2}{n}\right)n^3-48\sin\left(\dfrac{2}{n}\right)n^2+32\cos\left(\dfrac{2}{n}\right)n+16\sin\left(\dfrac{2}{n}\right)\right)$$

so presumably taking the limit of this should also yield the same result.